# custom title bar is not working android

Tags: android

Hi i have set up a custom title bar but the app crashes and i don't get any error log in LogCat, i'm going crazy. Here's is some code, can you experts see what's wrong?

```
boolean isCustomTitleSupported;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        isCustomTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
        customizeTitleBar("My Title");

    public void customizeTitleBar(String title){
        if(isCustomTitleSupported){
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.customtitlebar);
            TextView customTitleText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.customtitle);
            customTitleText.setText(title);
            customTitleText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
```

**customtitlebar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/customtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="3px" 
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

some help will be appreciated

Thanks!!

**EDIT:** i noticed that i wasn't extending Activity but BaseActivity a superclass i created to have the menu available in all of my activities. So i changed back to extend Activity and it's working but this is a problem because i need menus too. Is there any tricks so i could keep extending BaseActivity and even get the title bar to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to extract the `customtitle` TextView from the wrong layout.  When you use `findViewById` it defaults to your current activity's layout, which you set to `R.layout.about`.  You need to use a layout inflater to inflate `R.layout.customtitlebar` and then call `findViewById` from that (since the `customtitle` view is in the `customtitlebar` layout).

Something like this:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtitlebar);
TextView customTitleText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customtitle);
```

Comment: Before i continue trying to accomplish this i have a question. Is it possible to make the title bar height bigger? because i will be placing different buttons there depending on the activity.

Comment: Not entirely sure about that.  However, another option is to make your own title bar and not use the built-in one.  Then, you have much more control over things like height, etc. Check out this project for source code: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the title bar before setting the content view ?

```
customizeTitleBar("My Title");
setContentView(R.layout.about);
```

Comment: yes it doesn't work. Check out the edit i posted in the previous post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be half working now, but no title is being set, i mean that i get an empty title bar here's is what i got:

**About.java**

```
public class About extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        customizeTitleBar("APP TITLE");

        setContentView(R.layout.about);

        }   
}
```

**BaseActivity.java**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    boolean isCustomTitleSupported;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        isCustomTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        customizeTitleBar("MY TITLE");

    }

    public void customizeTitleBar(String title){
        if(isCustomTitleSupported){
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.customtitlebar);
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtitlebar, null);

            TextView customTitleText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customtitle);

            customTitleText.setText(title);
            customTitleText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Request the windowfeature --> setContentView --> customize Title

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Boolean customTitle = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);    
    setContentView(R.layout.listviewoffers);
    customTitle(R.string.dashboard_offers, 0, R.id.listViewTitle, customTitle);
```

This are the first lines of my onCreate.
The customTitle() is in my superclass.

```
    public void customTitle(int middle, int right, int altTitle, Boolean customTitle) {
    if (customTitle) {
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebarlayout);
        TextView titleMiddle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.middleTitleBar);
        titleMiddle.setText(getResources().getString(middle));

        TextView titleRight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rightTitleBar);
        if (right != 0) {
            titleRight.setText(getResources().getString(right));
        } else {
            titleRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(altTitle);
        title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dashboard_offers));
    }
}
```

It is a layout with 2 textviews, one in the middle, one in the right. The right can be set as gone.